# Does Safari cache old pages?

Tags: macos, safari, mobile-safari, web-browser

I have been having this problem probably ever since I bought my iMac. The Safari browser exhibits weird behaviour when I often navigate to a certain webpage. I do a lot of website development so naturally I have to test my sites. However, Safari seems to be keeping the old copy of the website in memory and keeps loading it! The only option is clearing the browsing data but that leads also to me getting logged out of all sites on the device so it's a pain.

An example of what happened today: I had a website that had a `<meta>` tag redirecting to www.anotherpage.com. I removed that tag and uploaded the file on FTP. However, Safari would still keep redirecting me to that page. When I accessed the same URL from mobile Safari version, everything worked as expected, no redirect. Heck, even Mozilla or Chrome on desktop showed the new site.

Should I just disable caching or am I missing something? Has anyone experienced similar problem? Or is it only one of the reasons why Safari is [becoming](https://nolanlawson.com/2015/06/30/safari-is-the-new-ie/) the new IE?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the cache Cmd-Alt-E?

Comment: I will try, thank you. I think it will fix the issue as clearing all data does it as well, but I was still wondering what might be the cause? I never experienced it on any other platform or browser. But then again I use Safari most of the time nowadays.

Comment: alt/reload used to get a fresh page. [I don't have anything to test on at the moment]

Comment: Seeing the same thing even with latest versions of both Safari and OSX other browsers no problem.
Relaunch of Safari doesn't resolve it neither do alt/reload of the page.
It's also like Safari doesn't care the header meta tag: my page frames sends (w/already expired TS) to attempt to tell browsers 'do not cache' as I want next refresh to load updated content. Auto refresh does normally work though.

Answer (score 2):

Safari aggressively caches redirects and force refresh will only force refresh the page you are redirected *to*, not the redirect itself. You can clear the cache without clearing your browsing data (cookies) by choosing Develop → Empty Caches (⌥⌘E).